# Draw Speech Bubble with auto size

Tags: android, xml

I'm building a chat and I'm trying to draw a speech bubble around a TextView, and I would like to adapt the bubble size according to the text length.

I already tried to insert the speech bubble drawable inside the textview, but I couldn't adjust the text inside the bubble, so I wrapped the textview inside a relative layout.

Right now, the bubble size doesn't change whatever the text is inside.

[Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0Bym.png)

Code (Chat Row):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="3sp"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/test"
        >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMsg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:textColor="#fdccc8"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="OneTwoThree"
        android:layout_marginStart="29dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Code (Speech Bubble shape)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="-45"
            android:pivotX="0%"
            android:pivotY="0%" >
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#da4131" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
    <item android:left="20dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#da4131"/>
            <corners
                android:radius="1dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
                android:topRightRadius="15dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: no, no ,no, just use a nine patch drawable, instead that tricks with shape rotate etc

Comment: ok, I will try to find a 9 patch generator

Comment: i dont think that with generator you will do what you want - just use gimp or whatever drawing tool and draw it by yourself ;-)

Comment: something like this: https://pasteboard.co/GDwwToW.png, save it as bubble.9.png and use as a TextView background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to me like it could be accomplished with a horizontal `LinearLayout` wrapping an `ImageView` (for the triangle) and a `TextView` (with a solid background that matches the triangle color). Android Studio will tell you that you should use `android:drawableLeft` instead of using a LinearLayout and two children, but I don't believe you could actually get the styling you want if you used that attribute.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/speech_left"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxWidth="240dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
        android:background="#f00"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: and instead of one `TextView` with right `Drawable` attached (nine patch drawable for example) you have to use 3 views to make such a simple thing...